# Unable to resolve module "react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js"

Tags: react-native

Found this issue a lot in my googling, but in old posts in where the resolution was a react-native version upgrade or other environmental issues that don't appear to the culprit.

I'm on 0.60.5 and out of ideas, Kubuntu 19.04 using yarn, Android Sdk 28, node 10.16.3

[image]

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: the `react-transform-hmr` project has been deprecated 4 years ago. perhaps, you can try sourcing another library for the feature you are working on.

Comment: I don't have it as one of my deps, how can I find what's looking for it?

Comment: perhaps, you can share your import statements for `jhizzle/wallet/index.js` above and troubleshoot further from there.